# Validating nested objects by making child object value optional based on parent value using JOI

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

I am trying to validate the below:

```
import { showErrors } from "./utils";

const data = {
  a: "test",
  b: "test",
  c: {
     //  d: ["x", "y"]
  }
};

const dataSchema = Joi.object({
  a: Joi.string().optional(),
  b: Joi.string().optional(),
  c: Joi.object({
    d: Joi.array().items("x","y")
  }).when(Joi.object({
    a: Joi.exist(),
    b: Joi.exist()
  }), {
    then:Joi.object({
      'd': Joi.optional()
    }),
    otherwise: Joi.object({
      'd': Joi.required()
    })
    
  })
});

showErrors(dataSchema.validate(data));
```

Idea is to make c.d optional with both `a` and `b` are present as `strings`. The code below should do the trick but for some reason it is always 'requiring' c.d !!

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider placing your `.when` in your initial object and not in your `c` object?

```
Joi.object({
  a: Joi.string(),
  b: Joi.string(),
  c: Joi.object({
   d: Joi.array().items("x","y")
  }),
}).when(Joi.object({ a: Joi.exist(), b: Joi.exist() }).unknown(), {
  then: Joi.object({ // this is optional
    c: Joi.object({
      d: Joi.optional()
    })
  }),
  otherwise: Joi.object({
    c: Joi.object({
      d: Joi.required()
    }).required()
  })
})
```

Also, you should use `unknow()`, and inside `then` and `otherwise` you must specify `c.d` and not only `d`.

And if you want, you can remove the `then` since it is already your default.